# My CSS menu doesn't shrink when viewed on an ipad

Tags: css, dotnetnuke

I've created a sub-menu on my site: http://fredrikstad.dnn2.labora-portal.no/

The menu seems to work in every browser, but it appears to wide when it is viewed on an iPad. This doesn't look to good, and I would be most grateful for any help solving the issue.

Best regards
Asbjørn

Comment: Post the code here, we don't want to go searching around for code.

Answer (score 0):

Portal CSS, around line 21.

In #snarvei  you have a fixed width of 940px.

That fixed with will prevent your menu from shrinking. Remove that and your li float:left will start falling down as you shrink it.

Doesn't look great how it falls down like that but that is why your menu is fixed width and the answer to your question.